# Building Boost 1.52 with zlib as a static library

Tags: boost, build, zlib

I am working in windows with vs2012 running all builds though a python build script.  I am attempting to build Boost 1.52 and I need to link in zlib statically.  I have a build of zlib and by default it created both the static library zlib.lib and the dll zlib1.dll with the associated zdll.lib.  I then build the boost libraries with the switches:

```
-sZLIB_BINARY=zlib -sZLIB_INCLUDE=%s -sZLIB_LIBPATH=%s
```

where the %s are replaced with the appropiate folders.  I believe that this should cause a link to the static zlib.lib file.  I have an application that uses all of this.  I link in zlib.lib and run dependency walker of the final exe and get zlib1.dll.  I have no other dependencies on zlib so this is the only place that this can be coming from.  I have additionally added the switch

```
-sNO_ZLIB=0
```

I have looked though the installation doc at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html and can not find anything else that I am missing.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: I have solved this in the following way...

While looking for other links I found that in boost there is a 
    #pragma comment(zlib, BOOST_ZLIB_BINARY)
and this flag was set in the preprocessor settings in devenv for my final project to zdll.lib.  I adjusted this to zlib.lib and everything is working appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this in the following way... While looking for other links I found that in boost there is a

```
#  pragma comment(lib, BOOST_STRINGIZE(BOOST_ZLIB_BINARY))
```

and this flag BOOST_ZLIB_BINARY was set in the preprocessor settings in devenv for my final project to zdll.lib. I adjusted this to zlib.lib and everything is working appropriately.